# include different php depending on a variable without refresh

Tags: php, ajax, include, conditional-statements

After hours trying and reading i definitively need help.

My home page includes a PHP file which launches a process that I can't change.

I need a button that, on click, changes the included PHP file and refreshes the div with the new include.

Is their an easy way to do this?

```
<input name="Au chateau" type="submit" value="chateau">
<input name="Au relais" type="submit" value="relais">

if ( $Au chateau = "chateau") { include 'test.php' };
else {include 'test.php'};
```

and refresh the zone on click.

Comment: You could use divs to your home page and when the user hits the button, triggers a JS function to load a php file and place the content to the div

Comment: are you sure about IF > test.php ELSE > test.php ?

Comment: You mention AJAX as a tag, but haven't shown your code.

Comment: Use the load() function (JQuery) it's very simple

Comment: Thanks those are some good way to look for..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, and thanks singe batteur, sorry for my bad english.
I think i m on the good way thanks to you, the load function jquery seem s to be great. Actually my code is:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("button").click(function(){

$("#div1").load("test.php",function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){

if(statusTxt == "success")

alert("External content loaded successfully!");

if(statusTxt == "error")

alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);

});
});
});
</script>
```

### Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text

Get External Content

Not so bad, but my PHP file is not found. I suppose my url is wrong or may be PHP can t be read. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

PHP is executed on the server side, and the server transfer the final page to the client. Without refreshing the page, you cannot change the content.

If you want to change the content on the client side without refreshing, you can use Javascript.

Comment: `Without refreshing the page, you cannot change the content.` : AJAX

Comment: Sure, I talked with PHP only

Comment: thats why the sentence I highlighted is incorrect :)

Comment: This would have been better as a comment. You are correct PHP cannot but JS/jQuery Ajax will always bite you on this kind of answer.